# /bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, docker, makefile

I have written a script to find all running docker containers with a certain name and it works when I directly type it into my terminal but as soon as I put it a Makefile it throws an error

> /bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution

This is the script in makefile:

```
remote: FORCE
   docker ps -q --filter name=$$(tmp=$${PWD##*/} && printf "%s_workspace" "$${tmp//./}")
```

To clarify what that chunk after name= is doing, it's trying to get the current folder name and remove all .'s and append it to my container name which is workspace.

Comment: Great job on the downvote without any explanation :)

Comment: You doubled most of the `$`, but not all of them: `${PWD##*/}` would be `$${PWD##*/}`.

Comment: @chepner even after adding `$` there it still doesn't work

Comment: Does `/bin/sh` know about `${##}` and `${//}` substitutions?

Comment: @cxw `##` yes, `//` no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The substitution operator you are using isn't supported by `/bin/sh`. You need to tell `make` to use `bash` instead:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

If you want to keep your recipe POSIX-compatible, use `tr` instead:

```
remote: FORCE
        docker ps -q --filter name=$$(printf '%s_workspace' "$${PWD##*/}" | tr -d .)
```

If you are using GNU `make`, you might want to use

```
remote: FORCE
        docker ps -q --filter name=$(subst .,,$(notdir $(PWD)))_workspace
```

instead to let `make` to all the string processing itself.

Comment: you are right tr works! Thanks for taking the time and understanding my question :)